# Плавающий элемент с ограничением по скролу

Tags: javascript, position, fixed

Есть карточка товара с абсолютным позиционированием на определенной высоте от верха окна.
При скролле, доходя до этой карточки, она должна становиться плавающей с позицией fixed с top 0.
Дойдя до определенного блока, карточка должна перед ним остановиться, а скролить можно дальше уже без карточки.
Но возвращаясь назад, карточка вновь должна фиксироваться и возвращаться со скролом в свое изначальное абсолютное положение.

Задаюсь if (pageYoffset > расстояние до карточки && pageYoffset < расстояние до блока) {
Удалить класс с абсолютом, добавить класс с фиксом
} Else if (pageYoffset > расстоние до блока) {
Удалить класс с фиксом, добавить класс с абсолютом, задать высоту топ до этого блока
}

Но карточка в начале этой операции дергается, плывет, останавливается у блока, а на обратном пути вообще пропадает...

Может кто подскажет решение? Только без sticky

Answer (score 0):

7й пример отсюда http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/09/scroll-block.html

Вот код если ссылка в будущем перестанет работать.

Фиксируется два и более блока друг за другом
При листании вниз прилипает первый блок, когда родитель заканчивается — отлипает; прилипает второй, когда родитель заканчивается — отлипает; прилипает третий и т.д.

```
<style>
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
}
.stop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 101;
}
</style>

<header></header>
<main>
  <article id="article"></article>
  <aside id="aside1">
    <div>
      <div class="stickyDa"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="stickyDa"></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="stickyDa"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</main>
<footer></footer>

<script>
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#aside1 div.stickyDa')).forEach(function(a) {
var b = null, P = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
function Ascroll() {
  if (b == null) {
    var Sa = getComputedStyle(a, ''), s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < Sa.length; i++) {
      if (Sa[i].indexOf('overflow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('padding') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('border') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('outline') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('box-shadow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('background') == 0) {
        s += Sa[i] + ': ' +Sa.getPropertyValue(Sa[i]) + '; '
      }
    }
    b = document.createElement('div');
    b.style.cssText = s + ' box-sizing: border-box; width: ' + a.offsetWidth + 'px;';
    a.insertBefore(b, a.firstChild);
    var l = a.childNodes.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
      b.appendChild(a.childNodes[1]);
    }
    a.style.height = b.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
    a.style.padding = '0';
    a.style.border = '0';
  }
  var Ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
      R = Math.round(Ra.top + b.getBoundingClientRect().height - a.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + parseFloat(getComputedStyle(a.parentNode, '').paddingBottom.slice(0, -2)));
  if ((Ra.top - P) <= 0) {
    if ((Ra.top - P) <= R) {
      b.className = 'stop';
      b.style.top = - R +'px';
    } else {
      b.className = 'sticky';
      b.style.top = P + 'px';
    }
  } else {
    b.className = '';
    b.style.top = '';
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    a.children[0].style.width = getComputedStyle(a, '').width
  }, false);
}
})
</script>
```